# Why the image dont appear in the conference details page?

Tags: laravel

In the page "https://project.test" there is a img like:

```
<img src="{{ $conference->image == null ? '/img/5.png' : $conference->image }}"
```

And the image appear. The generated src is like "https://project.test/uploads/conferences/test.png".

But in the conference details page "https://project.test/conference/1/conference-test" using also:

```
<img src="{{ $conference->image == null ? '/img/5.png' : $conference->image }}"
```

The image dont appears. The generated src is like "https://project.test/conference/1/uploads/conferences/test.png".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to

```
<img src="{{ $conference->image == null ? url('img/5.png') : url($conference->image) }}"
```

Use the [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-url) function to generate the correct path to your images.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case there is no $confernece->image so the image 5.png should appear.

Comment: Is your `img/5.png` in the /public folder?

Comment: Yes in public/img/5.png.

Comment: Same thing, use `url('img/5.png')`

Comment: Thanks, but dont appear with "                        <img src="{{ $conference->image == null ?  url('img/5.png') : $conference->image }}" class="img-fluid"/>
".

Comment: In the home page the generated html for the img "
homepage:
<img class="card-img-top" style="max-height: 121px; border:1px solid #eee;" src="uploads/conferences/test.png" alt="Card image cap"> ".

Comment: You have to `url()` the `img/5.png` and `$conference->image`

Comment: In the conferende details page, the generated html "<img src="uploads/conferences/test.png" class="img-fluid">".

Comment: check again where the path you stored the image, also you can use `asset("img/5.png")`, type the image url in browser get 404 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code like this:

```
<img src="/{{ $conference->image or 'img/5.png' }}" />
```